# Loop to add data to complex JSON object

Tags: json, loops

I have a complex JSON Object like this:

```
var requestData = { __batchRequests: [ { __changeRequests: [
{ requestUri: "Customers", method: "POST", headers: { "Content-ID": "1" }, data: { 
    CustomerID: 400, CustomerName: "John"
}  }
] } ] };
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. Declare this object but with the variable **data** empty
2. With a loop, add items dynamically to the **data** object,

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too complex an object.  And it isn't JSON until it's converted into a string.
Right now, it's just plain-ol' JS objects and arrays.

Breaking that down into its elements might look like this:

```
var requestData = {};
requestData.__batchRequests = [];
requestData.__batchRequests[0] = {};
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests = [];
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0] = {};
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].requestUri = "Customers";
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].method = "POST";
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].headers = { "Content-ID" : "1" };
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].data = {};
```

Aside from the repeats, what do you see?
Personally, I see that `__changeRequests[0]` is an object as simple as:

```
var changeRequest = {
    requestUri : "Customers",
    method : "POST",
    headers : { "Content-ID" : "1" },
    data : {}
};
```

I also see that I can just push that onto my array of change requests:

```
requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests.push(changeRequest);
```

Right?

I also know that my `changeRequest` variable still points to the one that I just added to the array, and whatever I change on the object will show up as changed in the array's reference to the object, too:

```
changeRequest.data.CustomerName = "Bob";
changeRequest.data.CustomerID = "204";


requestData.__/*...*/changeRequests[0].data.CustomerName; // Bob
```

So how about writing yourself some helper-functions?

```
function extend (obj, additions) {
    var key;
    for (key in obj) { if (additions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key] = additions[key];
    }
}

function makeChangeRequest (url, method, headers, data) {
    var request = {
        requestUri : url,
        method : method,
        headers : {},
        data : {}
    };

    extend(request.headers, headers);
    extend(request.data, data);

    return request;
}

function getBatch (num) { return requestData.__batchRequests[num]; }


var changeReq = makeChangeRequest("Customers",
                                  "POST",
                                  { "Content-ID" : "1" },
                                  { CustomerName : "Bob", CustomerID : "2012" });

var batch = getBatch(0);

batch.__changeRequests.push(changeReq);
```

If you want to add more data to `changeReq.data` later:

```
extend(changeReq.data, { Address : "33 Nowhere Rd.", City : "Splitsville" });
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  your answer is very complete.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, you can initialize `data` with an empty associative array:

```
var requestData = { __batchRequests: [ { __changeRequests: [
{ requestUri: "Customers", method: "POST", headers: { "Content-ID": "1" }, data: {}  }
] } ] };
```

This next part assumes, perhaps incorrectly, that you can use jQuery. It also assumes that you have an array containing all of the relevant key value pairs.

```
var customerDeetsArray =[{CustomerID: 400}, {CustomerName: "John"}]; 

for (var i in customerDeetsArray) {
  requestData.data = $.extend(requestData.data, customerDeetsArray[i]);
}
```

See working example which makes use of console.debug:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Rh72/6/

Comment: but **data** is inside  `requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].data`. I think your code inside the `for` should be changed to: `requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].data = $.extend(requestData.__batchRequests[0].__changeRequests[0].data, customerDeetsArray[i]);`